# VFX Graph - Trying to simulate orbit movement particles around point in space

Tags: unity-game-engine, effect, particles

**What I try to do:**

I have a point in space A, and 3D orbit around it.

I create a firefly’s, which moving directly to orbit area.

After reach it, they change their path to orbital direction around point A with same speed.

**What I already try:**
Using Force blocs in Update for attraction or simulating orbital movement – it’s been really strait forward solution, but speed of particles is uncontrollable and directions is chaotic.

Using ratio of current position in world space, to set relative velocity for particle – its works perfectly fine in 2D space, but can’t find a way to use it in 3D. (Pic 1, GIF, and how it’s work for now)
[Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B54It.jpg)
[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXRak.gif)

**What I try to do now:**
I try to set XYZ vector position in local space for each particle relative to vector AB, where Y vector is “Continuous” of it. After that (I suppose :D) any constant vector XZ passed to particle, will allow to simulate it perfectly, but can’t find a way to approach it. (Pic 2)
[Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyVwi.png)